# How to show red negative files on in my HTML file?

Tags: python, css

I have a pandas dataframe in Python that I am displaying in an HTML.  I have a style.css file that have some basic formatting rules for my dataframe.  Now, for one column, I want it to display in red font when the values are negative.  I am not sure if I should do it in my Python code or my style.css.

Here is my style.css code:

```
body            { font-family: "Verdana", "Tahoma", sans-serif;}
a, h1, h2       { color: #377ba8; }
h1, h2          { margin: 0; }
h1              { font-size: 1.2em; border-bottom: 2px solid #eee; }
h2              { font-size: 1.6em; }

table.dataframe, .dataframe th, .dataframe td {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align:left;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.pandas_ds th {
    background-color: #00B0EF;
    color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(odd)       { background-color:#eee; }
tr:nth-child(even)  { background-color:#fff; }

tr:hover            { background-color: #ffae99;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to apply a `class` to the `<td>` element, with Python. Then use CSS to apply the formatting. CSS can't determine the content of tags.

For example, use the python to assign `<td class="negative">VALUE</td>` to any negative values, then in your CSS: `td.negative {color:#FF0000;}`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm still a bit confused.  Do you have some links to some documentation that I can read up on this?

Comment: @Eric I don't have any ideas for documentation off the top of my head. But CSS doesn't have a way to implement conditionals based on the element's value - which is what I understand you're attempting to do. Instead, you'd have to rely on Python to do the comparison (`if (value < 0)`), and then assign a specific class to the element with that value.